# Python :: bool(float('0.0')) -> returns False ? Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

`bool(float('0.0'))` -> returns `False`? Why?

Whereas I can easily type case `float('0.0')` as `0.0` without any exceptions.

Comment: Pro-tip: The inverse works the same: `float(False) -> 0.0`. `0` is *falsy*.

Comment: 0s are falsey in Python aren't they? And what exception?

Comment: what do you mean by "type case"? It seems weird that you wonder why `bool` returns a boolean, or did you expect True?

Comment: You may be under the impression that `bool(expression)` means "can this expression evaluate without crashing?" in which case you would be justified in your confusion about why `bool(float('0.0'))` evaluates to False when `float('0.0')` on its own does not crash. But that is not what bool does.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in many programming languages numerical value of `0` is treated as convertible to logical `False`. Conversely, you may try `bool(float('0.1'))` and see it's evaluated to `True` (as `0.1 != 0`).

Answer (score 0):

Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:

```
None

False

zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.

any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].

any empty mapping, for example, {}.

instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a __nonzero__() or __len__() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.2.5
```

All other values are considered true -- so objects of many types are always true.

Comment: float('0.0'), gives me a float object -> type<float>, question is how does bool(float('0.1')) -> True , where as bool(float('0.0')) -> False ,float('0.0') also returns type<float> (tested in cmd line...)